# Cakephp - How to get data from other model using associated model?

Tags: php, cakephp

How to Join two model table to get user name base on user_id?

*likesTable.php* - id | post_id | user_id

```
              1      5     23
```

*postTable.php* - id | like_id | user_id | content

```
               5     1    23    Hello
```

*userTable.php* -  id | user_name |

```
               23  sample_name
```

PostController

```
   $this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Likes'],
    ];
    $posts = $this->paginate($this->posts);
```

Cake PHP variables in view

```
 'likes' => object(App\Model\Entity\likes) id:4 {
 'id' => (int) 1
 'post_id' => (int) 5
 'user_id' => (int) 23   ***I want to get user name from this ID***
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add users with likes in container (Likes.Users)

```
$this->paginate = [
        'contain' => ['Users', 'Likes.Users'],
];
```

Comment: Didn't know the solution was this easy. Wow I always watch your cake php youtube tutorial more power :) hope you can do send email for cakephp 4